# Директива #pragma argsused и Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Скачал себе Visual Studio 2017. Транслирую старый проект, а в нем есть директивы #pragma argsused. И мне Visual Studio 2017 на голубом глазу выдает сообщение:

> warning C4068: неизвестная директива pragma

Вопросы:

1. Что это? Новая мода? Сколько лет производители компиляторов писали предупреждения, если параметр функции не используется и требовали явно указывать pragma argsused. И вдруг "неизвестная директива pragma".
2. Что же мне теперь весь код перелопачивать, вычеркивая pragma argsused?
3. А как другие трансляторы, GCC например? Тоже перестали понимать pragma argsused?

Comment: А какая версия MSVC понимала `#pragma argsused`?

Comment: Набор понимаемых `#pragma` у каждого компилятора свой. Поэтому использование `#pragma` не кросс-платформенно.

Comment: Вобщем как не пыжится Страуструп со своими мильенами стандартов языка С++, никакой стандартизации и в помине нет. Без танцев с бубнами перенести проект между компиляторами невозможно. Каждый ****** производитель компилятора обязательно подгадит. То прагму не так понимает, то еще что-то. А как-то меня GCC заставил везде в обращении к методам писать this->. И это при том, что на других трансляторах все работало и без всякого this->.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Конструкция `pragma` специально предусмотрена для использования компиляторами в собственных целей. *"А как-то меня GCC заставил везде в обращении к методам писать this->"* скорее всего у вас была проблема в коде.

Comment: @VTT: Думаю, это было в шаблонном коде, в котором не было какого-нибудь `using`.

Comment: [скорее всего у вас была проблема в коде] Поставил this-> и все заработало. А на двух других компиляторах работало без всякого this-> .

Comment: @pepsicoca1: Язык C++ _разрешает_ некроссплатформенные конструкции. А раз разрешено, то кто-то этим обязательно воспользуется. Се ля ви!

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Так вопрос в том, должна ли эта конструкция работать без `this->` или нет. То, что на двух других компиляторах оно работало как есть, не дает положительного ответа на этот вопрос.

Comment: [То, что на двух других компиляторах оно работало и так не дает положительного ответа на этот вопрос] Давно дело было. Точнее, во времена Visual Studio 2010. Но тут даже не вопрос "кто прав". Тут дело в так называемой стандартизации. Если один человек пишет типа "стандарты" и другие люди пишут компиляторы типа работающие по "стандарту", то почему у них такие расхождения в интерпретации "стандартов"? Яйцеголовых "стандартизаторов" развелось 100500 мильенов, а простому крестьянину куда податься? Сделайте хотя-бы чтобы у всех было "ОДИНАКОВО".

Comment: Дело в том, что во-первых стандарт С++ отдает часть поведения на откуп компиляторам как `implementation defined`, а во-вторых VS долгое время была очень далека от четкого следования стандартам. Вообще-то она и сейчас далека, но прогресс в этом плане за последнее время был значительный.

Comment: [Вообще-то она и сейчас далека] Тогда может стоит забить на стандарты? Раз все равно каждый дудит в свою дуду. И честно объявить: "Ребята, мы тут пишем и публикуем какую-то ерунду типа стандарты и типа все производители заявляют, что у них-то компилятор как раз самый стандартный. Но все равно если вы попытаетесь перенести проекты между компиляторами, то вам придется сделать 100500 исправлений в коде".

Comment: Пишите код, соответствующий стандарту - он будет компилироваться на компиляторах с поддержкой этого стандарта. А если заложились на какое-то спефическое поведение конкретно компилятора, то не надо ныть, что на других компиляторах оно не работает или работает не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вам следует перелопатить весь код, удаляя `#pragma argsused` и вставляя надлежащие блоки для указания, что параметр функции не используется. При желании такой блок можно спрятать в макрос.

```
void foo(int value)
{
    static_cast<void>(value); // not used
```

альтернативный вариант c использованием стандартного C++17 аттрибута `maybe_unused`

```
void foo([[maybe_unused]] int value)
```

Существенным моментом является то, что `argsused` всегда подавляет предупреждения сразу для всех аргументов, даже если часть из них не является потенциально неиспользуемыми.

Comment: Ужосна... :-( Каст к войду, Карл!!! В 21 веке, Карл!!!

Comment: [c использованием стандартного C++17 аттрибута] Закладываться на стандарт 2017 года бессмысленно. До него компиляторы допрыгают лет через 5 только.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Конкретно `[[maybe_unused]]` уже во всю поддерживается, в том числе в студии.

Answer (score 2):

[#pragma argsused](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/pndsnpragmaargsused_xml.html) является нестандартной директивой некой RAD Studio от Embarcadero, и к Visual Studio (как и к стандартному С++) не имеет никакого отношения. Ее аналогом в Visual Studio в какой-то мере является `#pragma warning(suppress:4100)`, однако, чтобы эта директива сработала, она должна быть расположена прямо перед функцией без промежуточных переносов строки (параметр suppress отключает предупреждение для следующей строки). Например, так:

```
#pragma warning(suppress:4100)
void func(int a, int b) {

}
```

Если это поведение соответствует argsused, проблему можно решить обычной автозаменой (*Правка -> Найти и заменить -> Заменить в файлах*).